# Draw extruded objects with pst-3dplot

Tags: pstricks, transparency

I would like to draw a plane with a hole in its middle. So far, I've only gone around this problem by plotting a white ellipse in the middle of my plane. However, I would like the hole to be actually a transparent field, not white. Here's my mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)

\pstThreeDSquare[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0,0,0)(0,2,0)(2,0,0)
\pstThreeDSquare[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid](0,0,0.8)(0,2,0)(2,0,0)
\pstThreeDEllipse[fillcolor=white,fillstyle=solid](1,1,0.8)(0,0.5,0)(0.5,0,0)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: what I've got so far]

I would like the white ellipse to be actually transparent. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the blue square must also be transparent, because the circle is on the blue not the red:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pstThreeDSquare[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0,0,0)(0,2,0)(2,0,0)
\pstThreeDSquare[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5](0,0,0.8)(0,2,0)(2,0,0)
\pstThreeDEllipse[fillcolor=white,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5](1,1,0.8)(0,0.5,0)(0.5,0,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

if you want the circle part to be totally clipped you have to use `\pscustom` for the blue fill area:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,1)
\pstThreeDSquare[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0,0,0)(0,2,0)(2,0,0)
\pscustom[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5,linestyle=none]{%
  \pstThreeDLine(0,2,0.8)(0,0,0.8)(2,0,0.8)(2,2,0.8)(1,2,0.8)(1,1.5,0.8)%3 1/2 lines and a line to the circle
  \pstThreeDEllipse(1,1,0.8)(0,0.5,0)(0.5,0,0)
  \pstThreeDLine(1,1.5,0.8)(1,2,0.8)(0,2,0.8)% Back to the square 
}
\pstThreeDSquare(0,0,0.8)(0,2,0)(2,0,0)
\pstThreeDEllipse(1,1,0.8)(0,0.5,0)(0.5,0,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, writing opacity=1 in your code produces exactly the output I want. Accepted !

Comment: `opacity=1` is the default. You do not need that setting

Comment: Why didn't you use `eofill` here?

Answer (score 1):

Layman's solution with `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    invclip/.style={
        clip,
        insert path={{[reset cm](-16383.99999pt,-16383.99999pt) rectangle (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt)}}
    }
}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill = red, opacity = 0.5] (-4,0) -- (0,-2) -- (4,0) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[yshift=2cm]
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path [invclip] (0,2) circle (1.5cm and .75cm);
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \draw[fill = blue, opacity = 0.5] (-4,0) -- (0,-2) -- (4,0) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the `even odd rule` for this: `\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(30:1cm)},y={(150:1cm)},z={(90:1cm)}]
\filldraw[red,draw=black,thick] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (0,3,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[blue,draw=black,thick,even odd rule] (0,0,1) -- (3,0,1) -- (3,3,1) -- (0,3,1) -- cycle (1.5,1.5,1) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @TomBombadil You are right. But I didn't want to use `z` co-ordinate :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for typing practice with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](0,2)(3,0)(6,2)(3,4)
    \pscustom[fillcolor=blue,opacity=.5,fillstyle=eofill]
    {
        \translate(0,2)
        \pspolygon(0,2)(3,0)(6,2)(3,4)
        \moveto(4.5,2)
        \psellipse(3,2)(1.5,.5)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]